# check our package in stacktrace

Tags: java, stack-trace

I have a stack trace array below

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
```

From the stack trace below I need to get the first line of mypackage.

```
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.checkClientException(AbstractClient.java:522)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:544)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:205)
    at $Proxy94.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.mypackage.service.BankBridgeServiceTest.test(BankBridgeServiceTest.java:507)
com.mypackage.service.BankBridgeServiceTest.test(BankBridgeServiceTest.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

I wrote the code like

```
for(StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTrace){
        if(!stackTraceElement.isNativeMethod())
        {
            System.out.println(stackTrace.toString())
            break;
        }
    }
```

But it is not working. Can you anyone help me on this?.

Answer (score 0):

Use stackTraces[0].getClassName() and figure out package from there.

Example

```
public class StackError {
    public static void throwEX() {
        int x = 4 / 0;
    }

    public static void method2() {
        throwEX();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            method2();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            StackTraceElement[] stackTraces = e.getStackTrace();
            if(!stackTraces[0].isNativeMethod())
            System.out.println("Class Name :: "+stackTraces[0].getClassName());

        }
    }
}
```

Output - Class Name :: content_management.School.service.StackError

Hope this helps

Comment: Sunil.. This gets the classname from first line itself because IsNativeMethod() checks only line number is -2 or not. But mypackage line is present in the 5th line. But it will change depend on errors thats where the pblm is.

Comment: Just thinking aloud, 

If your can loop through the stack trace one by one and if find class  matches some part of  your package structure say "com.mypackage" then you can capture that and break out of look ??

I am assuming that most of the time the initial package structure would be com.company.*